# php transfer variable to other page

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to upload a file using php,and i need to pass a value like id or some thing with the from the upload form page to the file that have php code plz look at this code:

```
<form  name = "file" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadpp.php" method="POST">
Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
<input type=button name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

can i send the value with the same post array??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hidden form fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
```

So in PHP, `$_POST['foo']` would give you `"bar"`

Alternatively you can add them as "GET parameters" into the form's action attribute:

```
<form ... action="uploadpp.php?foo=bar" ...>
```

And access that with `$_GET['foo']`

Comment: I'd recommend using $_POST, as you do not want anyone bookmarking your generated link.

Comment: I did
like this :
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value=<?echo($_GET["pro_id"]);?> />
but it didnt work

Comment: Well it should work; what HTML are you seeing in the browser?

Also, to avoid cross-site scripting flaws, you should use:
`<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["pro_id"]);?>" />`